# JQuery Conflicts with Primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jquery-1.5

I have included JQuery1.5 in the header of a JSF page. In that page there is a bunch of Primefaces components already coded. After I have included the `Jquery.js` in the header of the page, some primefaces components like `<p:commandButton>` loses their skin and `<p:fileUpload>` becomes looking like normal JSP `<input type="file">` and losing its AJAX capability entirely.

Is there a way to use JQuery safely along with primefaces(without conflict)?

Comment: I don't see why this question is marked with _This question has been asked before_. The linked question was asked 2 years after this question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had the same problem as described in the question. That's why I came up with the following solution:

Include the primefaces built-in jQuery library (currently 1.4.1) as including an own jQuery library leads to CSS formatting problems. Adding the `target="head"` attribute allows for specifying the tag everywhere - e.g. when using templating you not always have access to the `<head>` tag:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

The primefaces jQuery library is included by default in conflict mode. That means the `$()` shortcut cannot by used. To overcome this issue include the following line in a `<script>` or `<h:outputScript>` tag:

```
<h:outputScript target="head">
    // Add the $() function
    $ = jQuery;
    // Now you can use it
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ...
    });
</h:outputScript>
```

That's the best solution I could dig out so far, using primefaces 2.2.1.

Comment: In addition to Lars explanation above,

Primefaces doesn't automatically include jQuery on pages that don't use Primefaces components even if the Primefaces namespace was defined in the <html> tag, so you can either use the method explained by Lars above or change one of your components to use the Primefaces component implementation, say change <h:selectOneMenu> to <p:selectOneMenu>.

Answer (score 43):

Why not use the jquery bundles with PrimeFaces?

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

PrimeFaces 2.2.1 has jQuery 1.4.4 and 3.0(in development) has 1.5.1.

Comment: As a side note, 2.2.1's jquery has noconflict enabled by default and 3.0's doesn't have noconflict on.

Answer (score 7):

Many JavaScript libraries use **$** as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, **$** is just an alias for **jQuery**, so all functionality is available without using **$** . followings are some methods :

- Write `jQuery.noConflict();` before initialization of jQuery,see below

  ```
  jQuery.noConflict();
  $(document).ready(function(){
     // your jQuery code   
  });
  ```
- Create a different alias instead of jQuery to use in the rest of the script.

  ```
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   // Do something with jQuery
   j("div p").hide();
  ```
- Change all instance of **$** : Replace `$`  with `jQuery` in jQuery code block

  ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function){
         jQuery("div p").hide();
   })
  ```
- Completely move jQuery to a new namespace in another object.

  ```
  var dom = {};
  dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  // Do something with the new jQuery
  dom.query("div p").hide();
  ```
- Set scope of **$** to local instead of global

  ```
      // Method 1
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           $("div").hide();
      });


      // Method 2
      (function($) {
        /* some code that uses $ */ 
      })(jQuery);
  ```

  **Note :** this point comes with  one drawback, you will not have access to your other library's **$()** method.

[`Original Reference`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 6):

My solution is add this code in default page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

After that i use jquery with:

```
$j
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a '[noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict)' mode which allows it to play nicely side by side with other libraries.  I haven't used Primefaces components, so I don't know for sure, but if you include jQuery in noconflict mode, your problems will likely go away.

Answer (score 3):

My experience:

I had the same problem and never got it working with both jquery libs. (I use `jQuery` instead of `$` but never tried `jQuery.noConflict()`).

My solution was to use only the lib bundled with primefaces as described in Cagatays answer.

Comment: The same holds for me. I can only use the primefaces built-in jQuery; when using my own jQuery lib the CSS styles will be corrupted. That means I can use only the jQuery() function instead of $().

Answer (score 1):

to solve the conflict between Primefaces and jQuery avoid to import any external jQuery file, so to solve the problem import the jQuery files located in the primefaces jar

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />
```

and in your jQuery code replace the $ with jQuery.

Comment: Why not improve the 39 upvoted answer instead of creating an almost identical one?