# Integrating Primefaces with External JQuery Library

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, primefaces

I'm trying to integrate Primefaces and JQueryUI and I'm running into some issues.  Is there a proper way to integrate an external JQuery library with Primefaces?  Things that happen include dialog windows don't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days ago there was a [similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457292/jquery-conflicts-with-primefaces). Some experiences and workarounds there.

Quoting my own answer:

> My experience:
>
> I had the same problem and never got
>   it working with both jquery libs. (I
>   use jQuery instead of $ but never
>   tried jQuery.noConflict()).
>
> My solution was to use only the lib
>   bundled with primefaces.

Comment: And if you cannot control the external JQuery importing? For instance, when it is on legacy code and you cannot exclude it? Any suggestions?