# Exclude resources in Primefaces 2.2.1

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm using both Primefaces 2.2.1 and jQuery (latest version 1.7) in my application, and when using Primefaces I get jQuery included twice. I tried putting a
`<p:resources exclude="/jquery/jquery.js"/>` in the `<h:head>` tag but I still get an inclusion of jquery/jquery.js from Primefaces. FYI, I use them along with Spring Web Flow and JSF 2.0 in my project.
How can I exclude jquery from Primefaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (should not) exclude the jquery that comes with the primefaces library , cause some primefaces components rely on it (on that specific jQuery version)

Instead you should find a way to make this two jQuery librarys work together

Look in here : [JQuery Conflicts with Primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5510507/617373)