# Twitter Bootstrap with Primefaces (JSF)

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Primefaces 3.2 (perhaps it's related to JSF in general) with Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.2 (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap).

I've added to the starter-example (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html) a drop down menu with the following scripts in `<h:head>`:

```
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
<script src="/resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

This works fine on the JSF page, but if I add a simple `p:dataTable`

```
<p:dataTable var="i" value="#{testBean.list}">
  <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Item"/></f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{i}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

the dropdown menu is not working anymore. I suppose it's JavaScript related, but not sure where to search for this bug.

Comment: Can you please also post the relevant rendered HTML code.

Comment: Rendered HTML code is here: http://pastebin.com/avpKPnai

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you better use `h:outputScript` to load js files...

I think its cause of conflicts between primefaces jquery and the manually included one...

PrimeFaces 3.2 comes with jQuery 1.7.1, So...

Remove the

`<script src="/resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>` from your code

and modify your include in the following way in your `<h:head>` element

```
<f:facet name="first">
  <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap-dropdown.js"/>
```

Also take a look at [JQuery Conflicts with Primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5510507/617373) and related [resource ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207011).

Comment: The dropdown still does not work. With deactivated `p:dataTable` it's also not working. (I've removed the manual `<script src="/resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>`, is this ok?). jQuery should be loaded from Primefaces library, since this is rendered: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/erp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces"`

Comment: yes , it is ok to remove the manually loaded jquery  cause primefaces got 1.7.1 inside its jar...

Comment: On step forward: Without `p:dataTable` and without `target="head"` in the Primefaces script, the dropdown menu is working correctly with Primefaces jQuery. With `target=head` in `$ = jQuery;` its not working. Without the `target=head` or without the complete script it's working.

Comment: It seems to be the ordering of `primefaces-jquery` and `bootstrap.js` (without `p:dataTable`): If `primefaces-jquery` is before `bootstrap.js` it's not working. And this is the case if `p:dataTable` is there!

Comment: I've already tested this, the problem seems to be that primefaces-jquery is always before manual entries in `<h:head>` if `p:dataTable` is present. I think I will raise another question for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

there is an easier way to add this theme.

If you are using a **maven** project bases do this:

Add dependency

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>  
        <version>1.0.9</version>  
    </dependency>
```

*Or add a specific theme dependency*

Add this in your **web.xml**

```
    <context-param>
      <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
      <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

If you are not using Maven, download the jar manually and add It to your classpath:

http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/

References:

- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf?theme=bootstrap
- http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2139
- http://primefaces.org/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

You are including JQuery twice (Primefaces imports it automatically). Remove your manual import:

```
<script src="/erp/resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

and everything should work.

Comment: I can verify that JQuery is imported by Primefaces in the rendered output, but the DropDown menu does not work properly.