# primefaces default css theme overriden by custom template

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces

i have a datatable in with filtering, sorting n pagination functionalities.
all was working fine until i apllied a readymade design template to my application. the custom readymade template is overiding the default primefaces theme i guess. so datatable functionalities are not working... now i get a plain datatable with no theme... 
i want to apply the custom template just to enhance my app design but i also want to keep the primefaces component design as it is with no change. what should i do?
pls suggest a solution...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Scrip Master | Dashboard Admin</title> 

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="reset.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="text.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="layout.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jquery-ui-1.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jquery.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="custom.css"/>
```

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title"/>`

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="excanvas.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="facebox.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui-1.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery_002.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery_003.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery_005.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery_004.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="widgets.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="dashboard.js"/>

</h:head>
```

Comment: all that you added was a css? or some js also included? also look in your firebug console for some errors also you might wanna use <f:facet name="first"> <h:outputScript ..../><h:outputStylesheet.../> </f:facet> to make sure that your custom stuff will be loaded first... (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10205451/617373)

Comment: thanks for ur help, the css is working fine now but i guess there's some problem with jquery, still the datatable is not working... have a look at my code below and suggest some solution, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

all that you added was a css? or some js also included? also look in your firebug console for some errors also you might wanna use

```
<f:facet name="first"> 
   <h:outputScript ..../>
   <h:outputStylesheet.../> 
</f:facet>
```

to make sure that your custom stuff will be loaded first...

also look here [taking care of the order that js files being loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205318/twitter-bootstrap-with-primefaces-jsf/10205451#10205451)

are you by any chance trying to include your own jquery library ? or any other jquery plugin ?

**EDIT**

seems like a jquery conflict to me

remove the include of additional jquery library js file

and instead add the following

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript target="head">
    $ = jQuery;
</h:outputScript>
```

if wont work try wrapping it with `<f:facet name="first"> ... </f:facet>`

Comment: please re edit you original question by appending the code in the comment , so it will be readable... (also , if you find some other question helpful / useful to you you can +1 it :)

Comment: what name should i give to the <h:outputScript target="head">  ...? error: name attribute is missing(for h:outputScrip tag)

Comment: weird... never had this error... is it in your eclipse/netbeans ? or your web server says that ?

Comment: i also tried with <f:facet name="first">...still not working...i also removed all the custom jqueries, still the same, the datatable is not working

Comment: thanks mate for your help...actually i made a silly mistake - i forgot to give my <h:form> its id and was trying to access the missing id...