# PrimeFaces pie chart is not displayed in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to display primefaces pie chart in my JSF application.

Here is my xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <ui:include src="blocks/head.xhtml"/>

    <body>
    <ui:include src="blocks/header.xhtml"/>

        <p:pieChart id="sample"
                    value="#{pieChartBean.pieModel}"
                    legendPosition="w"
                    title="Sample Pie Chart"
                    style="width:400px;height:300px"/>

    <ui:include src="blocks/footer.xhtml"/>
    </body>
</f:view>
</HTML>
```

And here is my bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "pieChartBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PieChartBean implements Serializable {

   private PieChartModel pieModel;

    public PieChartBean() {
        createPieModel();
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {
        return pieModel;
    }

    private void createPieModel() {
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();

        pieModel.set("Brand 1", 540);
        pieModel.set("Brand 2", 325);
        pieModel.set("Brand 3", 702);
        pieModel.set("Brand 4", 421);
    }

}
```

I put the bean in the ViewScope, I also tried Session and Request scopes. Problem is that the chart is not displayed in the page. Any ideas where is the problem?

EDITED:
Strange is this that I tried to add some other component in the same xhmtl page, I added `<p:spinner/>` and it works. It is showed in my JSF page but chart is not.

EDITED 2:

Firebug:

```
<div id="sample" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
<script id="sample_s" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('PieChart','widget_sample',{id:'sample',data:[[["Brand 1",540],["Brand 2",325],["Brand 3",702],["Brand 4",421]]],title:'Sample Pie Chart',legend:{show:true,renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,location:'w'},axes:{xaxis:{},yaxis:{}}},'charts');});
</script>
```

If I look through the generated HTML source with firebug the code shown above is generated but in browser nothing is displayed.

Comment: your code seems right, that why I would try adding , private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; and also would check if removing (name = "pieChartBean") will do any good

Comment: No success. I tried both of your suggestions.

Comment: And do you get any kind of exception, or it is just not displayed ?

Comment: It is just not displayed, I have added global messages but any kind of any message is not shown.

Comment: nothing in the firebug too? also take a look at this thread... http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18336

Comment: I have edited my question, I have copied generated HTML source.

Comment: take a look at this http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18336#p56852 any good?

Comment: Recent versions of Primefaces use the HTML5 canvas object for displaying charts. Maybe your browser is not capable of HTML5? Or do you use an older PF version where flash was used to create charts?

Comment: @Daniel I tried solutions in this link. Nothing worked..

Comment: @Matt Handy I am using Firefox 12, Chrome 18.0, IE 9 all three browsers does not displays charts so all three is not capable of HTML5?

Comment: All of them should work.

Comment: try placing <h:body> and <h:head instead your old html <body> tag in your page , if no good then at this point I'd recommend to start tearing apart stuff from your project ,  <ui:include's templates and even <f:view ...

Comment: try placing <h:body> and <h:head instead your old html <body> tag in your page AND EVEN TRY wrapping the pie with h:form, if no good then at this point I'd recommend to start tearing apart stuff from your project , <ui:include's templates and even <f:view ...

Comment: I have tried to wrap chart with h:form, change body to h:body, tried to remove f:view, I also tried to leave only HTML root tag and p:pieChart. No success..

Comment: What version of primefaces do you use ?

Comment: I have found the problem. Somehow the primefaces does not have a "fiendship" with jquery. I do not know why but if I remove jquery from my app charts are displayed successfully. But there is other solution to this: in that page were is primefaces charts I have added a script line: "$.noConflict();". And every works fine. But I do not understand why, so if someone could help me with understanding this issue it would very great :)

Comment: It is because primefaces has native support for jQuery. So if you import your own jQuery.js file it will get in conflict. There is no need to import jQuery, you can use the one shipped with primefaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already told in comments that you've solved the problem, just to summarize it in answer so this can get closed :

The problem was that you've imported external jQuery.js file.

- Don't import your own library of jQuery, it will get in conflict with the one bundled with primefaces. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` then.
- If you are using older version of primefaces (like 2.2.1) look at this answer : [jQuery conflict with primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5510507/1317692)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problème and I try to solve it by adding this line in the .xhtlm

```
<h:head>
    <title>Graphe Prime Faces </title>
</h:head>
```

and when  I see you code you have same erroor like me , just add in you're page .xhml  this

code the shart pie will be  displayed i you're browser

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the tags "p:pieChart" into a panel tag p:panel

```
                <p:panel>
                <p:pieChart id="sample"
                value="#{pieChartBean.pieModel}"
                legendPosition="w"
                title="Sample Pie Chart"
                style="width:400px;height:300px"/>
                </p:panel>
```

Thas work for me.