# Even basic DOJO not working with JSF (2.0). No luck

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, dojo

I am very new to Dojo and was trying a tutorial on DOJO with JSF. I went through numerous link to understand how to integrate DOJO with JSF.

> DOJO version: 1.9 JSF Version: 2.0 with JSP

I wrote a code having both JSF and DOJO but apparently it is not working properly.

> First the dojo tags are not recognized in Eclipse (IDE). It is a pain
>   remembering each and every tag. Each tag in IDE is highlighted as
>   yellow indicating undefined attribute name. I Have no clue why i cannot press ALT+Space and get the components of dojo. Why even after including all the scripts, the components are not resolved.

Code Snippet:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/script/
         dojo_lib/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css");
         @import url("${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/script/
         dojo_lib/dojo/resources/dojo.css");
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var djConfig = {
                parseOnLoad: true,
                isDebug: false,
            };
    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/script/dojo_lib/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       dojo.require("dojo.parser");
       dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
       dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");
    </script>    

    <script type="text/javascript">   
       function dojoInit(){
            dijit.registry.byClass('dijit.form.ValidationTextBox').forEach(function(pane){
              pane.setValue(pane.domNode.previousSibling.value);
         });

         dijit.registry.byClass('dijit.form.Textarea').forEach(function(pane){
              pane.setValue(pane.domNode.previousSibling.value);
         });
       }

       dojo.addOnLoad(dojoInit);
    </script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setDojoValue(){
         dijit.registry.byClass('dijit.form.ValidationTextBox').forEach(function(pane){
              pane.domNode.previousSibling.value = pane.getValue();
         });

         dijit.registry.byClass('dijit.form.Textarea').forEach(function(pane){
              pane.domNode.previousSibling.value = pane.getValue();
         });
    } 
    </script> 

    </head>
    <body class="claro">


    <f:view>
         <h3>Project</h3>
         <h:form id="project">
         <table>
              <tbody>
           <tr>
    <td>Project name:</td>
    <td><h:inputHidden value="#{projectFormBean.projectName}"/><f:verbatim> 
         <input type="text" name="projectName" dojotype="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" regExp="[\w]+"
          required="true" invalidMessage="Invalid.Only Alphabets required" requiredMessage="Input Required"/></f:verbatim>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Project description: </td>
    <td><h:inputHidden value="#{projectFormBean.projectDescription}"/><f:verbatim> 
     <textarea dojotype="dijit.form.Textarea"  style="width:80%">
         </textarea></f:verbatim>
    </td>
    </tr> 
              </tbody>
         </table>

         <h:commandButton id="button_submit" actionListener="#{projectFormBean.invokeAction}" 
        value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="setDojoValue();"></h:commandButton>        
         </h:form>
    </f:view>

    <script>
            require([
                'dojo/parser',
                'dojo/domReady!'
            ], function(parser){
                parser.parse(); // tell dojo to check the DOM for widgets
            });
        </script>
    </body>         
    </html>
```

When the Page load, 3 components are visible as opposed to 2.

> a. Input text with 'X' marked. I cannot write into this component b.
>   Input text for Project Name. c. Text area for Project Description.

Following problems are faced:

> a. Component with X appears which should not appear. b. The project
>   name field has validation.However only after I put space in the input,
>   the validation fires. Else it does not fire. c. The validation message
>   is shown below the text area whereas ideally it should be shown right
>   below the respective component. d. On form submit, the validation is
>   not fired. I dont know whether the input value is correct or not. e.
>   NO VALUE is obtained in the Backing bean action listener. Both the
>   fields prints blank.

Someone please guide.

Comment: The JSF syntax looks like JSF 1.2 to me. Search for an example on how a basic JSF 2 page looks like

Comment: In cases like this like integrating jQuery with JSF, you must remember that JSF will act as HTML generator and the JSF components will be rendered as HTML components, as simple as that. *Integrating* a JS library with JSF is not rocket science. More info: [is it possible to use js library in a jsf project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10467391/1065197)

Comment: By the way, Eclipse doesn't provide support for JS libraries by default. Maybe you need a plugin to handle the DOJO syntax. You can search on the net about it or take it as a great experience to learn DOJO.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have easily integrated Jquery in my project. There is no problem at all.We use it extensively to serve many different purpose. What I am trying over here is to integrate DOJO. Learning will be a great exp no doubt, but the basic example should atleast work. This is far away from working properly.

Comment: to stop the undefined attribute warning try using data-dojo-type="widget.class" AND for the others use data-dojo-props="prop1:val,prop2:val2"...., unless there is a dojo pluggin for eclipse jsf, you will never get the autocompletition