# p:datatable with selectionMode as multiple

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

As per the primefaces document the selection should be a array. In the below code bean.selectedUsers is defined as "HasUsersVO[] selectedUsers" but the value of datatable is List. I am getting cast error as pasted at the bottom when i click the OK button after the datatable got filled.

```
                <p:dataTable id="userListTable" value="#{bean.peopleVOList}"
                    var="user" rowClasses="odd even" selection="#{bean.selectedUsers}" rowKey="#{user.userGuid}"
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px">
                    </p:column>
.....
.....
</p:dataTable>
```

## Error

```
22:59:16,962 INFO  [class com.zreflect.emyed.managedbean.circle.CircleController] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) *******************Outside getUsersList********************
22:59:38,943 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) [Lcom.user.PeopleVO; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lcom.user.PeopleVO; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:835) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataHelper.decodeMultipleSelection(DataHelper.java:262) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataHelper.decodeSelection(DataHelper.java:240) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:72) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
```

Comment: Did you try replacing array with list for selection?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Yes then i get a different error since it is not array. As per the document i need to give array for selection.

Comment: Did you try to debug primefaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception message and the stacktrace indicates that you've supplied a `PeopleVO[]` array behind `#{bean.peopleVOList}`. This is not right. It must be a `Collection`, preferably an `ArrayList<PeopleVO>`.

```
private List<PeopleVO> peopleVOList;
```

The `#{bean.selectedUsers}` must indeed be an `PeopleVO[]`. That part is fine.