# Focus an inputText when opening dialog in primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm actually using JSF with Primefaces, and I have a little trouble with an `p:inputText` in a `p:dialog`. Indeed I don't know how to give/keep the focus on the inputText when I open my dialog.

Here is my XHTML file :

```
<body>
    ...
    <p:commandButton id="add-movie-button" value="Add movie" onclick="searchdlg.show()" update="movie-list,text-search" actionListener="#{layout.clearMovieList}"/>  
    <p:dialog id="search-movie" header="Add movie" widgetVar="searchdlg" modal="true" resizable="false">    
        <h:outputLabel for="text-search" value="Movie title"/>  
        <p:inputText id="text-search" autocomplete="true" size="57" value="#{layout.searchedMovie}" style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="movie-list" listener="#{layout.searchMovie}"/>
        </p:inputText>
        ...
    </p:dialog>
    ...
</body>
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457292/jquery-conflicts-with-primefaces/5457378#5457378) to give the focus on my inputText when keyDown, but it doesn't change anything.

So have you any tips/advice/solution to keep the focus on an InputText in a dialog after its opening ?

Comment: Looks like you can focus the `<p:inputText>` using `onShow` JavaScript method on `<p:dialog>`. As a side note, make sure the `<p:dialog>` has its own `<h:form>` and is not inside one bigger form that contains other elements.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Why the `<p:dialog>` must have is own `<h:form>` not inside one bigger form ? Because I use only 1 big form in all my web page, up to now it wasn't a problem so if I can avoid to modify all my code to remove this big form it should be good. What is the inpact of having only 1 big form ?

Comment: Usually, people use `<p:dialog>` to edit a single element of a `<p:dataTable>`, in order to achieve this the `<p:dialog>` should be outside in its own form. That's why I give you that advice, but if it works for you having the `<p:dialog>` in a single big `<h:form>` then go with it.

Comment: I've tried your `onShow` solution and change `onclick="searchdlg.show()"` by `oncomplete="searchdlg.show()"` and it works now. Thanks for your solution