# Validation time focus is not working in PrimeFaces dialog

Tags: javascript, validation, jsf, primefaces, focus

I have a dialog into form that containing three input text fields.

When validation fire then that focus on first validation failed input text field. e.g In the second field if no value is input or is left empty then focus on second field.

I have try **`<p:focus>`** but it's not working on dialog but working fine in simple page.

```
<p:dialog id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" dynamic="true"
    draggable="true" modal="true" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip"
    appendTo="@(body)" onShow="adjustPositionning(this.id)" closable="true"
    header="Heading">
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{bean.resetData()}"
        update=":uploadfrm"></p:ajax>
    <h:form id="uploadfrm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:focus></p:focus>
        <h:panelGrid id="detailPnl" columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel for="Name" value="Name" />
            <p:inputText id="CndName" maxlength="190" value="#{bean.vo.name}"
                required="true" />
            <p:message for="CndName" showDetail="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="email" value="Email" />
            <p:inputText id="eamils" maxlength="290" value="#{bean.vo.email}"
                required="true">
                <f:validator validatorId="EmailValidator" />
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="eamils" showDetail="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="MobileNoLbl" value="Mobile No" />
            <p:inputText id="MobileNo" maxlength="290" value="#{bean.vo.no}">
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="MobileNo" showDetail="true" />

            <div align="center">
                <p:commandButton value="save" id="saveBtn"
                    styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" title="Save"
                    update="uploadfrm :frm" validateClient="true"
                    action="#{bean.onSubmit()}"
                    oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed)dlg.hide();"
                    onstart="modalDialog.show()" onsuccess="modalDialog.hide();" />
                <p:spacer width="10" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancelBtn"
                    styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-default" title="Cancel"
                    update="detailPnl" actionListener="#{bean.resetData()}"
                    oncomplete="dlg.hide();" immediate="true">
                    <p:resetInput target=":uploadfrm" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

suggest me other solution for this appreciable for me when using JavaScript or primefaces.

**Note:** Script should be client side I don't want to change my Java Code.

Comment: I don't see any `p:focus` tag being used, so I cannot investigate why it fails. Please create an [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje I remove `p:focus` because it's not work for me. I have already try I want alternative way to do same

Comment: Good luck then... I don't have the time to try to create alternative solutions, sorry

Comment: @Kukeltje now answer it that already I have try now you see any solutions  ?? I also  add property context in `p:focus` but still it's not work

Comment: Thanks, but there was more in my initial comment. And don't forget version info

Comment: I used primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.1 @Kukeltje

Comment: Please have a look on this question's comment section see if it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583674/focus-an-inputtext-when-opening-dialog-in-primefaces

Comment: Did you try a more recent version? 4.0 is for me to old to even investigate. Sorry

Comment: @Kukeltje whole project is builtin primefaces 4.0 I not migrate for this silly thing. I want solution for that I know very well know it's possible using primefaces 5.0 and 6.0 you have other  solution ?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi there is no answer :(

Comment: Please read my comment properly

Comment: I read comments also but still not to help. it's ok I will manage thanks for replied @SubodhJoshi

Comment: I said TRY, never said migrate. And if you know it works in 5.0 and 6.0, maybe look at some differences in the javascript source of the focus component and the dialog. Like mentioned before, I have to little time already and trying to find workarounds for somewhat older versions is not on my priority list, sorry.